# how can I convert jquery jtable into html table.

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

how can I convert jquery jtable into html table. So that I can use javascript to specified row or column. It creates html table automatically, but I can't find it.

here is my jsp file:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Status</title>
<%@include file="includes/header.jsp" %>
<script type="text/javascript">



        $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#StatusContainer').jtable({
                        title : 'Status List',
                        selecting: true, 
                        multiselect: true, 
                        selectingCheckboxes: true,
            prefix:'record.',

                        actions : {
                                listAction  : 'status-list.action',
                                createAction: 'status-create.action',
                                updateAction: 'status-update.action',
                                deleteAction: 'status-delete.action'
                        },
                        fields : {

statusId : {
                                        title : 'Id',
                                        width : '30%',
                                        key : true,
                                        list : true,
                                        create : false
                                },








            statusValue : {
                                        title : 'Status Value',
                                        width : '30%',
                                        edit : true
                                },



                        }
                ,
            formCreated:function(event, data){
                $.each(data.form.find(':input'), function (i, val){
                    val.name="record."+val.name;
                })
            },});
                $('#StatusContainer').jtable('load');
        });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="./includes/menu.jsp"></jsp:include>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column small-12">
        <h1>Status List</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="column small-12">
        <div id="StatusContainer"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

[This is the view of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKHnb.png)

Comment: include the actual mark-up rather than images, please. and be clear about what you need to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no official method to convert jTable to ordinary html table.
But using unofficial way, you can get the table string content like this:

> `$("#StatusContainer").data("hikJtable")._$table`

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery to find the table

```
$('#StatusContainer').find('table');
```

probably a more useful query would be

```
$('#StatusContainer').find('tbody tr').each(function () {
    // this will be each tr in the table
});
```

this can be useful for subtotalling etc, but to change the table, use the proper interface, addRecord or updateRecord which will synch the database.